# Node Express and SQLite3: return related many-to-many data as one object

Tags: node.js, express, sqlite

I have the following tables:

```
movies     genres     genres_movies
------     ------     -------------
id         id         id
title      name       genre_id
                      movie_id
```

Using SQLite3 and Node Express, how can I create a query (or queries) that will return the following, hypothetical, movie object?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Catapult: The Movie",
    "genres": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name" "documentary"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "comedy"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Sqlite version has the [JSON1 extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) enabled, something like:

```sql
PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;
CREATE TABLE movies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT);
CREATE TABLE genres(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE genres_movies(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                         , movie_id INTEGER REFERENCES movies(id)
                         , genre_id INTEGER REFERENCES genres(id)
                         );
CREATE INDEX gm_idx_movie_id ON genres_movies(movie_id);
INSERT INTO movies(id, title) VALUES (1, 'Catapult: The Movie')
                                   , (2, 'Deadpool')
                                   , (3, 'Dune');
INSERT INTO genres(id, name) VALUES (1, 'documentary'), (2, 'comedy');
INSERT INTO genres_movies(movie_id, genre_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2);
SELECT json_object('id', m.id
                 , 'title', m.title
                 , 'genres',
                   CASE WHEN g.id ISNULL THEN json_array()
                        ELSE json_group_array(json_object('id', g.id
                                                        , 'name', g.name))
                   END)
       AS movie
FROM movies AS m
LEFT JOIN genres_movies AS gm ON m.id = gm.movie_id
LEFT JOIN genres AS g ON g.id = gm.genre_id
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.id;
```

produces

```
movie                                                                                                  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"id":1,"title":"Catapult: The Movie","genres":[{"id":1,"name":"documentary"},{"id":2,"name":"comedy"}]}
{"id":2,"title":"Deadpool","genres":[{"id":2,"name":"comedy"}]}
{"id":3,"title":"Dune","genres":[]}
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you. I got busy, so I'll be checking it out in the next few days.

Comment: That worked great. If I may ask one more question, how would you filter those results based on the genre. Say, only return movies that have the genre `2`?

Comment: @crowhill - Adding a `HAVING g.id = 2` after the `GROUP BY` clause should do it.

Comment: I can't get `HAVING g.id = 2` to work. SQLite returns a syntax error.  If I do `WHERE g.id = 2`, that works. though it strips out the other genres from the results, which isn't great.