# Node and Sqlite: return has many results as one row

Tags: node.js, sqlite

I have Artists and I have Albums. Every Album has an Artist. Ultimately, what I want is an API that can return an Artist *with all of that Artist's albums*, all as a single response.

Using [this](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/tryit/query/sqlite-left-join/#2) convenient SQLite sandbox, but instead of the default query, I'm running this:

```
SELECT artists.name, albums.title
FROM artists
JOIN albums ON artists.ArtistId = albums.ArtistId
WHERE artists.ArtistId = 1;
```

You should get two rows for AC/DC:

```
1   AC/DC   For Those About To Rock We Salute You
1   AC/DC   Let There Be Rock
```

So, the question is, using Node and/or SQLite, how would you return a result to the user that includes the above information in a single row?

A few additional considerations:

1) I already [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714686/node-express-and-sqlite3-return-related-many-to-many-data-as-one-object) this question and, while the answer was definitely correct, it was also beyond my ability to parse and so I couldn't modify it to do anything else, so please take mercy on my front-end developing self and /r/explainlikeimfive. The async nature of Node is doing my head in, when it comes to databases.

2) I don't care what form the response comes in. String, array, JSON, not JSON, whatever. As long as it's simple. I can manipulate the result into whatever form I need.

Comment: Why not just build a String in JS with concatenation? You loop the result from SQL and build the String, seems like it would be straight forward, so I'm curious why/if that was an issue

Comment: The `group_concat()` function with an appropriate `GROUP BY` clause. Or `json_group_array()` if you're outputting JSON.